# Should I use a single transaction when doing a get followed by a put?

Tags: indexeddb

One could make the argument that nesting a single function inside another is not callback hell, but I am trying to get used to pulling functions outside of other functions so as to avoid the inevitable.

Here is an example of a .get/.put. My question has to do with the transaction. Should I put this into a single transaction?

I don't want to do a .get(myid).onsuccess=function() {}

```js
init()
function init() {
 var myTransaction = myDatabase.transaction(['myData'],'readwrite')
 var myObjectStore = myTransaction.objectStore('myData')
 var myRequest = myObjectStore.get(myid)
 var myValue = 0
 var myUpdate = update.bind(this,myid,myValue)
 myRequest.onsuccess = myUpdate
}
function update(argid,argValue,response) {
 var obj = response.target.result
 obj.myField = argValue
 var myTransaction = myDatabase.transaction(['myData'],'readwrite')
 var myObjectStore = myTransaction.objectStore('myData')
 myObjectStore.put(obj,argid) // todo: onsuccess & onerror
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasons for using a single transaction include (1) convenience and (2) data integrity. Integrity refers to the idea that if one request in the set of requests of the transaction fails, all of the requests should fail.

You seem to be mostly concerned with convenience here, but it isn't exactly clear what you find to be most convenient regarding the style of your code.

If you want real convenience, consider opening a cursor and using cursor.update instead of an explicit get and put. While a cursor is generally used to iterate over multiple objects there is nothing inherently wrong with using a cursor just to grab one object. In fact that is more or less what the get function does behind the scenes.

If you want to avoid nesting, just use Function.prototype.bind.

Example of using bind and cursor.update:

```
function getAndPut(db, id) {
  var tx = db.transaction(..., 'readwrite');
  var store = tx.objectStore(...);
  var request = store.openCursor(id);
  request.onsuccess = getAndPutOnSuccess.bind(request, id);
}

function getAndPutOnSuccess(id, event) {
  var cursor = event.target.result;
  if(!cursor) {
    console.log('did not find object with id', id);
    return;
  }
  // Get the object at the cursor's current position
  var obj = cursor.value;

  // Edit the object
  obj.prop1 = 'foo';
  obj.prop2 = 'bar';

  // 'put' the new object back, overwriting the old object
  cursor.update(obj);
}
```

The cursor is tied to a transaction; specifically the transaction used to open the cursor. `cursor.update` implicitly uses the same transaction. This is primarily for convenience.